# My bluetooth headset works, and Linphone works, but not together

Tags: alsa, bluetooth, bluez, telephony

I have my headset working via `bluez-alsa` and `~/.asoundrc`, and I have Linphone working. Can anyone clue me how to put 2+2 together and get Linphone working through my headset? Or any other softphone?

Answer (score 0):

I am using pulseaudio and blueman and when the headset is connected, all sounds are directed on it, so it works fine.